# Is it possible to recover an RSA modulus from its signatures?

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Let's say that you have some small number of RSA signatures of known data: you know some pairs $(m_k, c_k)$ such that ${c_k}^e \equiv m_k \pmod n$.  If you know $e$, because probably it's one of $\{3, 17, 65537\}$, is it possible to recover $n$?

Comment: Note: I tend to write ${c_k}^e\equiv m_k\pmod n$ using `\pmod` rather than `\mod` (thanks to Maarten Bodewes for making just that). Hint: by definition that means $n$ is a divisor of ${c_k}^e-m_k$, and you know or can guess everything in several of these expressions. Note: recovering $n$, which is normally assumed public, hardly qualifies as a _key recovery_ attack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

calculate
$$gcd(c_1^e - m_1 , c_2^e- m_2, \dots , c_k^e-m_k)$$

With a bit luck this should get $n$.
It will be an interesting exercise to calculate the probability of success based on the number of cleartect/ciphertext pairs.

Comment: How does a GCD work with numbers that are in the 134-million-bit range (2048-bit modulus and $e = 65537$)?

Comment: Any algorithm's complexity is some function which depends on the input  size of its parameters. I doubt that you find anything more efficient as a gcd calculation.

Comment: Even with just two signatures, the method will spit $n$ most of the times (>60%); and when it does not, it will almost always spit $n$ times a small integer, which is easy to factor out, revealing $n$. In Mathematica, computation time is not worth measuring for $e≤$ 257, and is like 40s for $e=$ 65537 and 2048-bit $n$. Using optimized GCD routines like that of [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) would give significant speedup.

Comment: Note: you really want to compute $\gcd(c_1^e -\widetilde{m_1},c_2^e -\widetilde{m_2})$ where $\widetilde{m_j}$ is $m_j$ modified by whatever **deterministic** padding is used for signature (identity for textbook RSA signature, RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5..). With randomized padding, the method won't work.

Comment: @fgrieu For simplification, I'm assuming that $m$ is the post-padding message, and that I know what it is (i.e. it's deterministic as in PKCS #1 v1.5).

Answer (score 4):

***Note:*** *In my answer below I neglected to consider that the the messages for the associated signatures are also known, and that this could enable the existence of a practical algorithm to recover the modulus. While I haven't done the legwork to verify, [fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/555/fgrieu)'s comment below indicates that recovery of the modulus may very well be practical. I'm leaving my original answer below for those who are curious.*

---

For any practical number of RSA signatures, no, you will not be able to recover the entirety of the modulus $n$. You can however, with enough signatures, come up with a reasonable estimate for the value of the most significant bits of $n$ using [*Frequentist analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem#Frequentist_analysis).

It was exactly this sort of characterization of the RSA modulus that [broke the key privacy scheme used on Australia's Health Care Card](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/10/attack-of-week-unpicking-plaid.html).

Comment: In the question, we know not only the signatures, but also the messages, thus we can do much better than Frequentist analysis. The method in [this other answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30301/555) does work (assuming any known deterministic padding scheme), as I just confirmed by experiment with realistic parameters. Even with just two (message, signature) pairs, and regardless of $e$, it will spit $n$ with odds better than 60%; and when it does not, it will almost always spit $n$ times a small factor, that is easily found and removed.

Comment: Footnote: if a randomized signature padding is used, e.g. [RSASSA-PSS of PKCS#1v2.2](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A78%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C314%2Cnull%5D), which is increasingly common, then the original answer applies, AFAIK.