# A way to get the public key of a RS256 JWT from its headers and payload?

Tags: jwt

I have a RS256 JWT, I'd like to find out its public key. Because I know the header, payload and I have the encrypted signature, is there a way to obtain the public key that made the signature from these elements?

Comment: Signatures are not encrypted, and are generated with the private key not the public key. They are _verified_ with the public key, and for a JWS (including a signed JWT) that key is usually either included in or identified by the header; see [rfc7515 section 6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#section-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RS256 is defined as "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256", i.e. an RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 signature. You can therefore find a method of obtaining the modulus [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30289/1172). Note that you'd first have to [perform the deterministic PKCS#1 v1.5 encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-9.2) on the payload itself to get to the $m$ within the question / answers.

If the public exponent is large & random then you're probably out of luck, but that's not common at all. Instead, the public exponent is usually small, often the value 0x010001 / 65537 - the fifth prime of Fermat, also known as F4. JWT only hints to use F4; [it doesn't seem to explicitly require a specific or small exponent to be used](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.2).

Comment: Note that I'm presuming that the signature is not actually encrypted. Saying that signature generation is encryption with a private key (for RSA) is a [**common mistake**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172) which I'm trying to fight (and loosing, because of all the terribly bad learning material out there).